# Do I need to explicitly mention every file in the file block?

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

I got a quick question about `azurem_function_app_function`'s file block property. I have a project with 3 azure functions, all in Python.

They all have several files, modules...etc.My question is the following: do I need to explicitly mention every file in the file block? Or does just mentioning the entrypoint file suffice? ie, is the following enough, or is that feature for simple functions?

```
resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "function" {
  name            = "function_name"
  function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.function_app.id
  language        = "Python"
  file {
    name    = "app.py"
    content = file("../function_name/app.py")
  }
  config_json = jsonencode({
    "bindings" = [{
      "name" : "mytimer",
      "type" : "timerTrigger",
      "direction" : "in",
      "schedule" : "0 */5 * * * *"
    }]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you include all files on which your function depends, including source code and any other necessary files such as configuration files, templates, or data files. If all of your other required files are in the same directory as `app.py`, the deployment package will include them. Suppose they are in a different directory or are not directly or indirectly imported by your Python code. In that case, you must include them explicitly in the file block to ensure they are included.

I hope I have been able to answer your question.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I guess the real question is whether it's intelligent enough to be recursive and go thru the different modules (explictly imported in `app.py`)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not intelligent enough to be recursive.